# AutoMapper - Map list of flat objects to complex object

Tags: automapper, .net-6.0

I'm using AutoMapper in a .NET 6 application to map multiple records from a source list to a list property in the destination object.

**Source Object:**

```
public class UserDetailDto
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
}
```

**Destination Object:**

```
public class UserDetail
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<UserAddress> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class UserAddress
{
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
}
```

**AutoMapper Mapping:**

```
CreateMap<UserDetailDto, UserDetail>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ID, src => src.MapFrom(_ => _.ID))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, src => src.MapFrom(_ => _.FirstName))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, src => src.MapFrom(_ => _.LastName));
```

In the above, a user can have multiple addresses. So from database, there will be multiple records for a user with different `Address1` and `Address2` but same `ID`, `FirstName` and `LastName`.

So, I need to do the mapping in such a way the for a user though there could be multiple records but after mapping it should have a single record with list of its addresses.

I am not sure how this can be achieved or even supported. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a custom type converter to map from `List<UserDetailDto>` to `List<UserDetail>`.

```cs
public class UserDetailDtoListToUserDetailListConverter : ITypeConverter<List<UserDetailDto>, List<UserDetail>>
{
    public List<UserDetail> Convert(List<UserDetailDto> source, List<UserDetail> destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        destination = new List<UserDetail>();

        foreach (var group in source.GroupBy(e => e.ID))
        {
            var firstItem = group.FirstOrDefault();

            var dto = context.Mapper.Map<UserDetail>(firstItem);
            dto.Addresses = context.Mapper.Map<List<UserAddress>>(group);

            destination.Add(dto);
        }

        return destination;
    }
}
```

Mapping rules:

```cs
CreateMap<UserDetailDto, UserDetail>();
            
CreateMap<UserDetailDto, UserAddress>();

CreateMap<List<UserDetailDto>, List<UserDetail>>()
    .ConvertUsing<UserDetailDtoListToUserDetailListConverter>();
```

Usage:

```
var userDetailList = _mapper.Map<List<UserDetail>>(userDetailDtoList);
```

Note that by default AutoMapper will automatically map from the source object to the destination object with the same member name, so you don't need to specify the member mapping with the same name.

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ytPEBT)

Comment: You code looks good but how does it ensure that the addresses are mapped only for the ID it belongs

Comment: You mean that your source could have different users?

Comment: Yes. It is a list that can have multiple users and each user can have multiple records if the address are different

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. But you seems to be not clear about the question. Multiple records of UserDetailDto for a single user will be mapped to a single object of UserDetail with the Addresses property having addresses from all the records for that user

Comment: The first implementation is based on what you ask, from multiple UserDetailDTO to combine into a single UserDetail consists of multiple addresses.

Comment: I updated your answer and now that works fine

Comment: Hi, by the way I know why you mention not working, you need the rule: `CreateMap<IEnumerable<UserDetailDto>, UserDetail>()`

Comment: The answer was getting confused with other suggestions then the actual fix so I modified it to have the working solution only